# Java regular expression extract data

Tags: java, regex

I have the following `String`:

```
String s = "ddddddddddd@Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd}"
```

How would I use Java regular expressions to extract it to:

```
Type=aaaa
Type=dddddddddd
```

Comment: You question is not clear, please define exactly which data you need to match and capture. Your "Type=aaaa" simply is not part of your given data and can't be captured at all.

Comment: yeah,  there are some, i need to extract all of pattern like this. @XXX={xxxx}

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Extract
{
    public static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Type=)(\\{(.*?)\\})+");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ddddddddddd@Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd}";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            // Capture group 1 = "Type="
            System.out.print(m.group(1));   
            // Capture group 3 is what's between the curly braces
            System.out.println(m.group(3)); 
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

> Type=aaaa 
>   Type=dddddddddd

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Extract {
    public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(@)(\\w+)(=\\{)(d\\s*)+(})|(@)(\\w+)(=\\{)(a\\s*)+(})");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ddddddddddd@Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd}";


        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(s);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The regexp seems wrong to me, it matches all ds and as, but captures only one of them. Should be (d+)|(a+) I guess.

Comment: And that's what i thought so , that it should match either d's or a's. For e.g if input is dddddddddddaaa@Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd} then my program print's <br/>ddddddddddd <br/>
aaa<br/>
aaaa<br/>
ddddddddddddddddd<br/>
dddddddddd<br/>

Comment: your expresion seems to be a little question, it can't work for me.a
a
a
a
a
d
a
d
a
a
a

Comment: @NicqChen , if you want to have all a's or d's including space character then just use (d\s*)+|(a\s*)+

Comment: actually i would like to extract data with @XX={XXX} pattern. but i always extract @Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd} with pattern (@.*=)(\\{.*?\\}), i think question is .*?

Comment: thanks, sol4me. it can work, but it still can not solve my question. what i need to extract like @XXXX={XXXXX} pattern. your solution only can extract a or d.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read on regular expressions on your own, Java already provides a documentation and there are plenty of tools out there to test regular expressions for a given string. One possibility for your problem may be:

```
"Type=\\{((?:a|d)+)\\}"
```

[Docs in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

[QuickREx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickrex/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "ddddddddddd@Type={aaaa}ddddddddddddddddd@Type={dddddddddd}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@Type=\\{.*?\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            match = "Type=" + match.substring(7, match.length() - 1);
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i change Type to others words. this can't work for me.

Comment: That's why you should lear to take some time and ask detailled questions, you question doesn't say anything about "other words" than "Type".